# OpenGL make rotation function give vector

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

Is there a way to record `glrotatef()` rotation so that I can get a directional vector out of it? For example, I have drawn a line on the Y-Axis. I then rotate using `glrotatef()` to get the new line in light blue. The rotation function (to my understanding) moves the "screen" such that everything is rotated. How can I get the information of the new light blue line? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using glGet, you can get the current Modelview matrix (that is used to store all your transformations, including the rotation you just made).

```
GLfloat matrix[16]; 
glGetFloatv (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
```

It is then up to you to multiply your vector with this matrix to get the resulting vector after the transformation. Look here for reference: http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication